# How to set up a Excel sheet so that if I add new cols or rows, ASP still recognizes those cols and rows as part of the original tables I was reading

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

Hello friends from SO.

I'm just starting to learn how to read data from Excel sheets (using OLEDB) and I must confess I find it easy when you only have a single table in the sheet.

But I got confused when I have to read data from multiple tables in the same sheet, even more when I know I have to read from a part in a table where new columns can be added (see "RETURNS#" columns in the second table in the image bellow)

[image]
As I mentioned earlier, I'm really new to reading data from excel , so I don't know if it'll be **necessary to do some kind of special configuration** in the sheet so that I can easily tell which data comes from the first table and which comes from the second table and what's more even if I'd add more "RETURNS#" columns to the second table,those new columns could still be recognized as part of the "RETURNS#" section(RETURN 1,RETURN 2)

I'd really appreciate if you could ***guide me***, perhaps recommending me some articles on this topic,or by which keywords search for them, or by explaining (if possible) how you would handle such scenario.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. If you don't understand what I explained (due to my bad English) please tell me which part you didn't understand and I'll try to rewrite it.
And just in case it help you understand the template I'm planning to use, here's a [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/lsr4be7yli01ntc/template.xlsx) to it